# iPhone - Adding new sections and rows into UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` to display a list of data.

The list will contain images, so I am loading images with lazy loading. Now I don't want to load the whole list at a time.

The loading should be like, first it should load some 10 records and when we scrolling down to the `tableview`, it should automatically load next 10 records as on.

For this I need to add rows when I am scrolling to bottom. The `tableview` may contain different sections.

So how can I add new rows and new sections at the end of the `tableview` while scrolling down?

Answer (score 1):

At

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
     if (indexPath.row == [yourArray count]-1)
        {
         //start fetching the next set of data in background asynchronously and when fetching is complete use delegate methods to reload or append your current UITableView , meanwhile start a activity indicator as footer to show loading
         }
   }
```

this is the effective method, if you try to implement synchronously when scrolling reaches bottom, it will make your device stuck

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [Apple documentation about UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).
You can use the following method to add a row :

```
- (void)insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the thing you want to do is known as **Lazy Loading**.

Means your table view will load images or show data in the cells which are currently visible to user. So have a look at [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html) link. It provides sample code that might help you.

And to insert row, you can use

```
(void)insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;
```